# Find whether an event (with a start & end time) goes beyond a certain time (e.g. 6pm) in dataframe using Python (pandas, datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a Python program using pandas and datetime libraries that will calculate the pay from my casual job each week, so I can cross reference my bank statement instead of looking through payslips.
The data that I am analysing is from the Google Calendar API that is synced with my work schedule. It prints the events in that particular calendar to a csv file in this format:

|  | Start | End | Title | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 02.12.2020 07:00 | 02.12.2020 16:00 | Shift | 9.0 |
| 1 | 04.12.2020 18:00 | 04.12.2020 21:00 | Shift | 3.0 |
| 2 | 05.12.2020 07:00 | 05.12.2020 12:00 | Shift | 5.0 |
| 3 | 06.12.2020 09:00 | 06.12.2020 18:00 | Shift | 9.0 |
| 4 | 07.12.2020 19:00 | 07.12.2020 23:00 | Shift | 4.0 |
| 5 | 08.12.2020 19:00 | 08.12.2020 23:00 | Shift | 4.0 |
| 6 | 09.12.2020 10:00 | 09.12.2020 15:00 | Shift | 5.0 |

As I am a casual at this job I have to take a few things into consideration like penalty rates (baserate, after 6pm on Monday - Friday, Saturday, and Sunday all have different rates). I'm wondering if I can analyse this csv using datetime and calculate how many hours are before 6pm, and how many after 6pm. So using this as an example the output would be like:

|  | Start | End | Title | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04.12.2020 15:00 | 04.12.2020 21:00 | Shift | 6.0 |

|  | Start | End | Title | Total Hours | Hours before 3pm | Hours after 3pm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04.12.2020 15:00 | 04.12.2020 21:00 | Shift | 6.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 |

I can use this to get the day of the week but I'm just not sure how to analyse certain bits of time for penalty rates:

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['Start'].dt.day_name()
```

I appreciate any help in Python or even other coding languages/techniques this can be applied to:)

Edit:
This is how my dataframe is looking at the moment

|  | Start | End | Title | Hours | day_of_week | Pay | week_of_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-12-02 07:00:00 | 2020-12-02 16:00:00 | Shift | 9.0 | Wednesday | 337.30 | 49 |

**EDIT**
In response to David Erickson's comment.

|  | value | variable | bool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-12-02 07:00:00 | Start | False |
| 1 | 2020-12-02 08:00:00 | Start | False |
| 2 | 2020-12-02 09:00:00 | Start | False |
| 3 | 2020-12-02 10:00:00 | Start | False |
| 4 | 2020-12-02 11:00:00 | Start | False |
| 5 | 2020-12-02 12:00:00 | Start | False |
| 6 | 2020-12-02 13:00:00 | Start | False |
| 7 | 2020-12-02 14:00:00 | Start | False |
| 8 | 2020-12-02 15:00:00 | Start | False |
| 9 | 2020-12-02 16:00:00 | **End** | False |
| 10 | 2020-12-04 18:00:00 | **Start** | False |
| 11 | 2020-12-04 19:00:00 | Start | True |
| 12 | 2020-12-04 20:00:00 | Start | True |
| 13 | 2020-12-04 21:00:00 | **End** | True |
| 14 | 2020-12-05 07:00:00 | **Start** | False |
| 15 | 2020-12-05 08:00:00 | Start | False |
| 16 | 2020-12-05 09:00:00 | Start | False |
| 17 | 2020-12-05 10:00:00 | Start | False |
| 18 | 2020-12-05 11:00:00 | Start | False |
| 19 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00 | **End** | False |
| 20 | 2020-12-06 09:00:00 | **Start** | False |
| 21 | 2020-12-06 10:00:00 | Start | False |
| 22 | 2020-12-06 11:00:00 | Start | False |
| 23 | 2020-12-06 12:00:00 | Start | False |
| 24 | 2020-12-06 13:00:00 | Start | False |
| 25 | 2020-12-06 14:00:00 | Start | False |
| 26 | 2020-12-06 15:00:00 | Start | False |
| 27 | 2020-12-06 6:00:00 | Start | False |
| 28 | 2020-12-06 17:00:00 | Start | False |
| 29 | 2020-12-06 18:00:00 | **End** | False |
| 30 | 2020-12-07 19:00:00 | **Start** | False |
| 31 | 2020-12-07 20:00:00 | Start | True |
| 32 | 2020-12-07 21:00:00 | Start | True |
| 33 | 2020-12-07 22:00:00 | Start | True |
| 34 | 2020-12-07 23:00:00 | **End** | True |
| 35 | 2020-12-08 19:00:00 | **Start** | False |
| 36 | 2020-12-08 20:00:00 | Start | True |
| 37 | 2020-12-08 21:00:00 | Start | True |
| 38 | 2020-12-08 22:00:00 | Start | True |
| 39 | 2020-12-08 23:00:00 | **End** | True |
| 40 | 2020-12-09 10:00:00 | **Start** | False |
| 41 | 2020-12-09 11:00:00 | Start | False |
| 42 | 2020-12-09 12:00:00 | Start | False |
| 43 | 2020-12-09 13:00:00 | Start | False |
| 44 | 2020-12-09 14:00:00 | Start | False |
| 45 | 2020-12-09 15:00:00 | **End** | False |
| 46 | 2020-12-11 19:00:00 | **Start** | False |
| 47 | 2020-12-11 20:00:00 | Start | True |
| 48 | 2020-12-11 21:00:00 | Start | True |
| 49 | 2020-12-11 22:00:00 | Start | True |

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: (2020-12-19)**

I have simply filtered out the `Start` rows, as you were correct an extra row wa being calculated. Also, I passed `dayfirst=True` to `pd.to_datetime()` to convert the date correctly. I have also made the output clean with some extra columns.

```
higher_pay = 40
lower_pay = 30

df['Start'], df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True), pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True)
start = df['Start']
df1 = df[['Start', 'End']].melt(value_name='Date').set_index('Date')
s = df1.groupby('variable').cumcount()
df1 = df1.groupby(s, group_keys=False).resample('1H').asfreq().join(s.rename('Shift').to_frame()).ffill().reset_index()
df1 = df1[~df1['Date'].isin(start)]
df1['Day'] = df1['Date'].dt.day_name()
df1['Week'] = df1['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
m = (df1['Date'].dt.hour > 18) | (df1['Day'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday']))
df1['Higher Pay Hours'] = np.where(m, 1, 0)
df1['Lower Pay Hours'] = np.where(m, 0, 1)
df1['Pay'] = np.where(m, higher_pay, lower_pay)
df1 = df1.groupby(['Shift', 'Day', 'Week']).sum().reset_index()
df2 = df.merge(df1, how='left', left_index=True, right_on='Shift').drop('Shift', axis=1)
df2
Out[1]: 
                Start                 End  Title  Hours        Day  Week  \
0 2020-12-02 07:00:00 2020-12-02 16:00:00  Shift    9.0  Wednesday    49   
1 2020-12-04 18:00:00 2020-12-04 21:00:00  Shift    3.0     Friday    49   
2 2020-12-05 07:00:00 2020-12-05 12:00:00  Shift    5.0   Saturday    49   
3 2020-12-06 09:00:00 2020-12-06 18:00:00  Shift    9.0     Sunday    49   
4 2020-12-07 19:00:00 2020-12-07 23:00:00  Shift    4.0     Monday    50   
5 2020-12-08 19:00:00 2020-12-08 23:00:00  Shift    4.0    Tuesday    50   
6 2020-12-09 10:00:00 2020-12-09 15:00:00  Shift    5.0  Wednesday    50   

   Higher Pay Hours  Lower Pay Hours  Pay  
0                 0                9  270  
1                 3                0  120  
2                 5                0  200  
3                 9                0  360  
4                 4                0  160  
5                 4                0  160  
6                 0                5  150
```

---

There are probably more concise ways to do this, but I thought resampling the dataframe and then counting the hours would be a clean approach. You can `melt` the dataframe to have `Start` and `End` in the same column and fill in the gap hours with `resample` making sure to `groupby` by the 'Start' and 'End' values that were initially on the same row. The easiest way to figure out which rows were initially together is to get the cumulative count with `cumcount` of the values in the new the dataframe grouped by 'Start' and 'End'. I'll show you how this works later in the answer.

Full Code:

```
df['Start'], df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start']), pd.to_datetime(df['End'])
df = df[['Start', 'End']].melt().set_index('value')
df = df.groupby(df.groupby('variable').cumcount(), group_keys=False).resample('1H').asfreq().ffill().reset_index()
m = (df['value'].dt.hour > 18) | (df['value'].dt.day_name().isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday']))
print('Normal Rate No. of Hours', df[m].shape[0])
print('Higher Rate No. of Hours', df[~m].shape[0])
Normal Rate No. of Hours 20
Higher Rate No. of Hours 26
```

Adding some more details...

**Step 1: Melt the dataframe:** *You only need two columns 'Start' and 'End' to get your desired output*

```
df = df[['Start', 'End']].melt().set_index('value')
df
Out[1]: 
                    variable
value                       
2020-02-12 07:00:00    Start
2020-04-12 18:00:00    Start
2020-05-12 07:00:00    Start
2020-06-12 09:00:00    Start
2020-07-12 19:00:00    Start
2020-08-12 19:00:00    Start
2020-09-12 10:00:00    Start
2020-02-12 16:00:00      End
2020-04-12 21:00:00      End
2020-05-12 12:00:00      End
2020-06-12 18:00:00      End
2020-07-12 23:00:00      End
2020-08-12 23:00:00      End
2020-09-12 15:00:00      End
```

**Step 2: Create Group in preparation for resample:** *As you can see group 0-6 line up with each other representing '
Start' and 'End' as they were together previously

```
df.groupby('variable').cumcount()
Out[2]: 
value
2020-02-12 07:00:00    0
2020-04-12 18:00:00    1
2020-05-12 07:00:00    2
2020-06-12 09:00:00    3
2020-07-12 19:00:00    4
2020-08-12 19:00:00    5
2020-09-12 10:00:00    6
2020-02-12 16:00:00    0
2020-04-12 21:00:00    1
2020-05-12 12:00:00    2
2020-06-12 18:00:00    3
2020-07-12 23:00:00    4
2020-08-12 23:00:00    5
2020-09-12 15:00:00    6
```

**Step 3: Resample the data per group by hour to fill in the gaps for each group:**

```
df.groupby(df.groupby('variable').cumcount(), group_keys=False).resample('1H').asfreq().ffill().reset_index()
Out[3]: 
                 value variable
0  2020-02-12 07:00:00    Start
1  2020-02-12 08:00:00    Start
2  2020-02-12 09:00:00    Start
3  2020-02-12 10:00:00    Start
4  2020-02-12 11:00:00    Start
5  2020-02-12 12:00:00    Start
6  2020-02-12 13:00:00    Start
7  2020-02-12 14:00:00    Start
8  2020-02-12 15:00:00    Start
9  2020-02-12 16:00:00      End
10 2020-04-12 18:00:00    Start
11 2020-04-12 19:00:00    Start
12 2020-04-12 20:00:00    Start
13 2020-04-12 21:00:00      End
14 2020-05-12 07:00:00    Start
15 2020-05-12 08:00:00    Start
16 2020-05-12 09:00:00    Start
17 2020-05-12 10:00:00    Start
18 2020-05-12 11:00:00    Start
19 2020-05-12 12:00:00      End
20 2020-06-12 09:00:00    Start
21 2020-06-12 10:00:00    Start
22 2020-06-12 11:00:00    Start
23 2020-06-12 12:00:00    Start
24 2020-06-12 13:00:00    Start
25 2020-06-12 14:00:00    Start
26 2020-06-12 15:00:00    Start
27 2020-06-12 16:00:00    Start
28 2020-06-12 17:00:00    Start
29 2020-06-12 18:00:00      End
30 2020-07-12 19:00:00    Start
31 2020-07-12 20:00:00    Start
32 2020-07-12 21:00:00    Start
33 2020-07-12 22:00:00    Start
34 2020-07-12 23:00:00      End
35 2020-08-12 19:00:00    Start
36 2020-08-12 20:00:00    Start
37 2020-08-12 21:00:00    Start
38 2020-08-12 22:00:00    Start
39 2020-08-12 23:00:00      End
40 2020-09-12 10:00:00    Start
41 2020-09-12 11:00:00    Start
42 2020-09-12 12:00:00    Start
43 2020-09-12 13:00:00    Start
44 2020-09-12 14:00:00    Start
45 2020-09-12 15:00:00      End
```

**Step 4 - From there, you can calculate the boolean series I have called `m`:** *True values represent conditions met for "Higher Rate".

```
m = (df['value'].dt.hour > 18) | (df['value'].dt.day_name().isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday']))
m
Out[4]: 
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14    False
15    False
16    False
17    False
18    False
19    False
20    False
21    False
22    False
23    False
24    False
25    False
26    False
27    False
28    False
29    False
30     True
31     True
32     True
33     True
34     True
35     True
36     True
37     True
38     True
39     True
40     True
41     True
42     True
43     True
44     True
45     True
```

**Step 5: Filter the dataframe by `True` or `False` to count total hours for the Normal Rate and Higher Rate and print values.**

```
print('Normal Rate No. of Hours', df[m].shape[0])
print('Higher Rate No. of Hours', df[~m].shape[0])
Normal Rate No. of Hours 20
Higher Rate No. of Hours 26
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this! Definitely put me on the right track with the melt function. Only thing I'm trying to work out now is that if the start of a shift is past 6pm (7pm for example) then that will be counted as an hour (instead of working until 8pm being counted as an hour). So I'm trying to iterate through the 'variable' column and if the row before i is 'End', change to False because that would mean it's the beginning of the shift. Let me know if you have any ideas in the meantime. Appreciate the help David.

Comment: @tyleroki In your question, can you share the expected output in the form of the `True` / '`False` boolean series that I show in step 4? Essentially, can you copy Step Output into your questiond and change True to False or False to True of anything that is not expected?

Comment: sorry for my late response. I've updated my question to show what I'm after. Basically whenever 'Start' is underneath 'End' in the variable column, then bool should be False. This is because the shift is starting so therefore no time has passed (e.g. if a shift starts at 7pm this shouldn't be counted as true)